# Adding blf to the bottom center of all 3d views?

Tags: python

I've tried using `draw_handler_add()` on both `area.spaces[0]` and `SpaceView3D` but I can't seem to find a way to add text to different 3d Views in Blender and have the text position depend on the size of a given area.

For example, I wanted to try adding text to the middle of every 3D View but I can only manage to add it in the same relative position for each view.

Comment: I think it is not possible without modify the main program in source code

Comment: You need to use wm (window manager) ops for this, but I don't have time to write a demo code just now.